# How to enable actions on my published post

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

i make a post to my wall throgh facebook api
it works well but there is no actions as like, comment, share in the bottom of the post
how can i enable it?

i make a http post to thie url:
    https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?    access_token=xxx&message=xxx&link=xxx&picture=xxx&name=xxx&caption=xxx&description=xxx

Answer (score 0):

using feed dialog on client apps;
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

on that link, there are example calls also thru Graph API

Let me try to add example params you need when you make HTTP POST call;

```
Map<String, String>  fbParams = new HashMap<String, String>();

String actions="{\"name\": \""+ "name of your app" +"\""+
", \"link\": \""+ "link to your app, webpage etc" +"\"}";

fbParams.put("message",message);// NOTE: leave empty, let user enter this via dialog
fbParams.put("picture",picture_static);
//fbParams.putString("source", picture_static);// only 'picture' param is enough
fbParams.put("link",link);
fbParams.put("name",name);
fbParams.put("description",description);
fbParams.put("caption","using BlablaApp"); 
fbParams.put("actions",actions);
```

Comment: Thanks WareNinja
is'nt there an option to make it without dialog?
if you'll here (under post):
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/
there is an argument named actions
but i don't know the right values for that

Comment: But how can i add comments, share and like links in the bottom of the post?

Comment: like, comment comes as standard, any extra actions should be part of 'actions' attribute.  see facebook doc "actions  A JSON array containing a single object describing the action link which will appear next to the "Comment" and "Like" link under posts. The contained object must have the keys name and link."

Comment: this is exactly my problem
like, comment doesnt come as standard

Comment: sorry, only the share link is missing for me